# Weird Characters on SQL Database - Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, azure

Running my asp net mvc application on visual studio locally when querying the database shows special characters normally (mainly accents, like ão and é) but when I uploaded my DB to Azure it shows weird stuff. For example, when querying a table locally it displays "São Paulo" but when querying it on Azure it shows "SÒo Paulo"

The Collation used on Azure is Latin1_General_CI_AS.

What can I do?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Sql Azure default collation is 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' and you can't change. It means that you should set the collation at your column level.

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id    int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    c1    nvarchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
    c2    nvarchar(20) COLLATE Japanese_CI_AS
)
```

Probably, you are setting a different collation in your column level. Just remove that and it will work. Let the default collation.

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id    int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    c1    nvarchar(20) not null,
    c2    nvarchar(20) null
)
```

More info in here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/06/11/10023650.aspx